# Misbehaviour of OLEDBDataAdapter or Datatable

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledbcommand, oledbdataadapter

I am developing a Desktop application in VB.Net, its Database is Microsoft Access 2013 Database.
however i have encountered a weird problem, i don't know what might be the reason.
The query(statement) i am using returns data correctly in Access but when it comes to get the data using OledbAdapters it returns blank in last two columns.

My Query Statement is as below,(I have copied Query statement from Text Visualizer of OledbCommand.Selectcommand property, and tested it for result in Access Query)

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Sal_Statement.TotalPay) AS SumOfTotalPay
SELECT Sal_Statement.ZoneName, Sal_Statement.District, Sal_Statement.Empid, Sal_Statement.PANNum, Sal_Statement.BankName, Sal_Statement.IFSCCode, Sal_Statement.AccountNumber
FROM Sal_Statement
WHERE ((([Amonth] & "-" & [AYear])="Apr-2014" Or ([Amonth] & "-" & [AYear])="May-2014" Or ([Amonth] & "-" & [AYear])="Jun-2014" Or ([Amonth] & "-" & [AYear])="Jul-2014" Or ([Amonth] & "-" & [AYear])="Aug-2014" Or ([Amonth] & "-" & [AYear])="Sep-2014" Or ([Amonth] & "-" & [AYear])="Oct-2014" Or ([Amonth] & "-" & [AYear])="Nov-2014" Or ([Amonth] & "-" & [AYear])="Dec-2014" Or ([Amonth] & "-" & [AYear])="Jan-2015" Or ([Amonth] & "-" & [AYear])="Feb-2015" Or ([Amonth] & "-" & [AYear])="Mar-2015"))
GROUP BY Sal_Statement.ZoneName, Sal_Statement.District, Sal_Statement.Empid, Sal_Statement.PANNum, Sal_Statement.BankName, Sal_Statement.IFSCCode, Sal_Statement.AccountNumber
PIVOT [Ayear] & "-" & IIf([AMonth]="Jan",1,IIf([Amonth]="Feb",2,IIf([Amonth]="Mar",3,IIf([amonth]="Apr",4,IIf([amonth]="May",5,IIf([amonth]="Jun",6,IIf([amonth]="Jul",7,IIf([amonth]="Aug",8,IIf([amonth]="Sep",9,IIf([amonth]="Oct",10,IIf([amonth]="Nov",11,12)))))))))));
```

Result in Access

[Image1: Result in MSAccess - Observe Last Two Columns returned by Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOTUc.png)
.

Same Query Statement returns DataTable as shown in Next Image

[Image2: Result in DataTable-Last Two Columns are missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fErmx.png)

Comment: Dear Fellas, I am really stuck on issue...